# What is the solution set of $ \displaystyle\log _x\left({x+5\over 1-3x}\right)>0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

What is the solution set of $ \displaystyle\log _x\left({x+5\over 1-3x}\right)>0$?

I'm getting $0 < x < 1/3$ but that is wrong answer.

Comment: If $x<1$, then $\log_x y>0$ when $0 < y <1$, not when $y>1$. More precisely: $\log_x y > 0$ if $x<1$ and $y<1$, or if $x>1$ and $y>1$.

Comment: But the condition of the problem initially was not written as it is now

Comment: If you have a good enough reputation, you can click on "edit", and that shows that the person actually typed. It was log_x{(x+5)/(1-3x)}.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\displaystyle y={x+5\over 1-3x}$. Then $\log_x y >0$ if $x>1$ and $y>1$, or if $0<x<1$ and $0<y<1$.

If $x>1$, then $y$ is a positive number divided by a negative number, so is negative.

Hence, we only need to consider when $x<1$. That means we must have
$$0 < {x+5\over 1-3x} < 1.$$
If $x<{1\over3}$, then $1-3x>0$ and we get
$$0<x+5 < 1-3x$$ which means $x>-5$ (automatic) and $4x < -4$ or $x<-1$ (impossible).

If $x>{1\over3}$, then $1-3x<0$, and we get
$$0 > x+5 > 1-3x$$ which means $x<-5$ (impossible).

Thus there are NO values of $x$ where $\displaystyle\log _x {x+5\over 1-3x}>0$!

Comment: I can't understand the meaning of if x>1 then y is a positive number divided by a negative number.Which negative number?

Comment: If $x>1$, then $x+5>6$ and $1-3x <1-3\cdot1=-2<0$. Then $\displaystyle y={x+5\over 1-3x} = {+\over -} < 0$.

Answer (score 0):

See we can re arrange our inequation as $$\frac{x+5}{1-3x}<1$$ so it becomes $x+5<1-3x$ reversal of equality takes place due to log. But there exists no positive x such that $x+5<1-3x$ note we can take $0$ as log to base $0$ isnt defined. Thus there is no x satisfying the equation